# IE7 line break inside div messes up bottom margin

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-7, line, break

I noticed strange behavior in IE7 that does not occur in Firefox.
If you notice in "testing 2" "div",when I add 2 line breaks at the bottom of this div,
it does not respect margin set up for this div, and "test 3" div is right below it without margins. When I remove "br" then "test 2" and "test 3" divs have margins between them.

Is this IE7 bug or is there a workaround for this?

```
    <div style="border: dotted 1px red;">

    <div id="main" style="border: solid 1px black; padding: 10px; margin: 5px; float:left ">
    testing 1


       <div style="border: solid 1px black; padding: 10px; margin: 10px;">
             testing 2
             <br><br>       <!--   THIS LINE -->
         </div>


        <div style="border: solid 1px black; padding: 10px; margin: 10px; ">

        testing 3
        </div>


    </div>

    <div style="border: solid 1px black; padding: 10px; margin: 20px; float: left">

        testing 4
    </div>

    <div style="clear:both"></div>

    </div>

<\html><\body>
```

Comment: As a side remark, it looks like you got the </html> and </body> closing tags in the wrong order and using the wrong slash (\ in stead of /). Use "</body></html>" instead.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about why IE is doing this, but one reasonably neat solution is to wrap the contents of the "testing 2" div with another div, like so:

```
<div style="border: solid 1px black; padding: 10px; margin: 10px;">
    <div>
        testing 2
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <!--   THIS LINE -->
    </div>
</div>
```

However I'd advise to not use <br/> if you can help it; get it all sorted using CSS if you can! :)

Answer (score 1):

IE7 does indeed have issues with [nested elements and their margins](http://www.brunildo.org/test/IEMargCollLay.html).

You can fix this by forcing the 'testing 2' `div` to [have layout](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html).

In this instance, setting `height:100%;` on the 'testing 2' `div` will get the margins back. I have created a [working example](http://webignition.net/examples/ie7nestedelementmargin/) to demonstrate the fix.

It is worth noting that a significant proportion of IE CSS bugs can be resolved by either forcing or removing layout from an element.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the nicest solution, but adding a non-breaking space after the 
 tags help:
Change

```
 <br><br>       <!--   THIS LINE -->
```

into:

```
 <br><br>&nbsp;       <!--   THIS LINE -->
```

... Okay for some reason it won't come through... the non-breaking space is "& nbsp;" (without the quotes and without the space in between)

Comment: Sorry for pushing your answer to the bottom by editing it.  Tried to fix the   issue, but failed.

Comment: That's fine, i think people get the point. Thanks for trying :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `<br>`, use `padding-bottom` **after** the `padding` rule, on your div.

Answer (score 0):

Semantically, you should be placing that text within a `<p>`, `<blockquote>`, or other block-level element. Try to avoid placing text directly within a `<div>` as they are intended to be used for indicating divisions or sections within a page.

For example:

```
<div style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 10px; margin: 10px;">
    <p style="margin: 0 0 10px 0;">testing 2</p>
</div>
```

This solves your problem in IE7 and will render more consistently across other browsers as well.